# See if a string is accepted by an NFA

Tags: java, hashmap, nlp, nfa

I've implemented a method that scans in NFAs written in a certain format. It uses a HashMap> where the first State is the current state, the string in the map is the symbol that causes transition, and the state in the second map is the state it goes to. I can load the NFA into this just fine.

My issue is finding strings that match it. The next part of the program scans in a series of symbols, such as "a" "b" "c", and needs to judge whether or not the currently loaded NFA accepts them. Currently I have this:

```
    public static boolean search(State state, int track){
    String s = inputS[track];
    state.visited = true;
    System.out.println("state: " + state.label);
    System.out.println("input" + s);
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<State>> p = FSA.get(state);
    if(p.containsKey(s)){
        track++;
        if(track == inputS.length-1 && state == finalState){
            return true;
        }
        for(State st : p.get(s)){
            if(st.visited == false){
                return search(st, track);
            }
        }
    } 

return false;   
}
```

the inputS array is the array of symbols in the string I'm judging. I'm having trouble accounting for situations where the line reads into the NFA but does not end at an accept state, I know I need to backtrack somehow to keep searching...Thanks in advance for helping.